# What's a good naming convention for a lookup map/hash?

Tags: language-agnostic, naming-conventions

In data processing, I frequently need to create a lookup data structure to map one identifier to another. As a concrete example, let's take a structure which holds a 1-to-1 mapping between a country's 2 character code and its full name. In it we would have

```
AD -> Andorra   
AE -> United Arab Emirates  
AF -> Afghanistan
```

What's a good name for the variable that would hold this map? Some ideas (I'll use camel-case names):

```
countryNameByCode
nameByCodeLookup
nameCodeLookup
codeToName
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My vote would be for `codeToName` in this particular case, and I guess that generalizes. That's not to say that it's the name I would have chosen myself in all cases; that depends a lot on scope, further encapsulation, and so on. But it feels like a good name, that should help make your code readable:

```
String country = codeToName["SV"];
```

Looks fairly nice, should be easily understandable by anyone. Possibly change the word "code" to something more precise ("countrycode" would be my next choice).

Answer (score 6):

```
country_name = countries_by_code[country_code]
```

It passes the “telephone dictation” test, and also sounds more like natural language.

Answer (score 3):

I like to use plurals for collections.

```
countryNames
```

Edit: `countryCodes` is wrong because you are mapping from a code to a name.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it this way:

countryCodeMappingByName

Or if the mapping is unique, just simply:

countryCodeMapping

Comment: really? I can't imagine having to type that every time I use that hashmap.

Comment: I know its a bit long for a variable name, but its not ambigious, which I think is important...

Answer (score 0):

Use something which sounds right when pronouncing it. This also means name your key variables appropriately. Example:

```
countryName = countries[countryCode];
```

This makes perfect sense - you give `countries` a `countryCode`, and it returns a `countryName`. This would be redundant:

```
countryName = countryCodesToNames[countryCode];
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#, I'd call a type that does this `CountryCodeToNameMapping`.  Usually I'd call a variable `countryCodeToNameMapping`, but in certain very restricted contexts (*e.g.*, lambdas), I'd probably call it `c` or `m`.

Answer (score 0):

I would choose

```
countryName = countryByCode["DE"]
```

unless you have a class *Country* in your code in which case I would choose

```
countryName = countryNameByCode["DE"]
```

It is clear, succinct, and reads easily.

A map is not first and foremost a collection, but, well, a map. Hence, I would not choose names like `countries` or `countriesByCode`. Depending on the context, it might *sometimes* be reasonable to emphasize the argument of the map (see [unwind's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/217628/10716984)). But personally, I think in your case,

```
countryName = CountryCodeToName["DE"]
```

or something similar does not reflect your intentions (getting a country name) as well as the name(s) given above.

Answer (score -1):

Another vote for just pluralizing what you're mapping to.

eg. `country = countries[code]`